# Why does Glassfish drop tables on deploy?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I used the following command to deploy updates of my *.ear file on Glassfish 3/4 and to keep (but disable) the old version of the *.ear file:

```
./asadmin --user admin deploy --name MyProject:0.9.2 --createtables=false --dropandcreatetables=false --enabled=true --force=true /home/updates/MyProject.ear
```

This always worked without touching the database. I have applied database changes manually by a script.

But suddenly this does not work anymore. The application deploys correctly, but the database is being dropped and newly created...

My Glassfish version is currently 4.0/b89. Does anybody know if there's a bug in with the **asadmin deploy** command ? Any other ideas how to deploy without dropping the database?

EDIT1: Btw: I'm using Eclipse-Link 2.4 as JPA-provider (if this helps...)

EDIT2: I now tried every possible combination (using only --createtables=false OR --dropandcreatetables=false), but nothing seems to work. The database is dropped everytime. I realized, that if the table-creation-strategy is set to "none" in the persistence.xml, it does work for subsequent deployments (without dropping the database). But the asadmin/deploy or also redeploy command should override the persistence.xml settings as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/deploy-1.html#SJSASEEREFMANdeploy-1) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/redeploy-1.html#SJSASEEREFMANredeploy-1) when the --dropandcreatetables option is set to false.

Comment: Just checking (I'm no expert), but don't you want redeploy, not deploy?

Comment: I want to keep the old version on the server (disabled). So I could easily switch back, if anything goes wrong during the update process. With "redeploy", the old version is overwritten. Moreover, the --name option incl. verison-identifier does not work with "redeploy"; it says that MyProject:0.9.3 is not deployed, since the currently deployed predecessor version is named MyProject:0.9.2. These tools are some kind of buggy ...

Answer (score 1):

According to

> asadmin help deploy

and

> asadmin help redeploy

for 4.0/b89, you should only use one of these? Indicated by the | in the help.

"The --createtables and --dropandcreatetables options are mutually exclusive; only one should be used."

Iain

Comment: hi lain - thanks for your suggestion. I'll try this one tomorrow at work and give some feedback. Btw: I'm using Eclipse-Link 2.4 as JPA provider (updated my question).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work (cp. EDIT 2 in the question). any other ideas?

Comment: Sadly no better ideas. Hopefully this activity will lure in an expert? Good luck.

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway Iain! I found a work-around by setting "create only" (without drop) in persistence.xml. I now have to compile twice, for the installer and the update, it's not as bad as all that. I've more headache when realizing that those override-options at asadmin/deploy do not work... hope it's not getting worse with the next update of GF4+ ... ;-) probably I'll contact some expert as you suggested and will report back to this thread when I got an answer. Thanks!